# PCSX crashes after opening bin file

Tags: 15.04, emulation, pcsx2

When I'm opening bin files in pcsx it loads for a second and then it crashes. I'm getting this error (--sync, doesn't make any difference):

```
jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ pcsx --sync
RGB mode found.  id: 18424752, depth: 24
The program 'pcsx' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)'.
  (Details: serial 75 error_code 1 request_code 150 minor_code 19)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ gdk_x_error
```

anyone that could help me fix this?

Comment: Relevant bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1457179 -- FWIW, looking at the web it seems that people had successfully run pcsx installing the .deb from here: http://pcsxr.codeplex.com/releases/view/50048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to choose the NVidia driver, I used this ppa: **ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa** ([OMG Ubuntu : Ubuntu NVIDIA Graphics Drivers PPA Is Ready For Action](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/08/ubuntu-nvidia-graphics-drivers-ppa-is-ready-for-action))

[image]

Then Open the NVIDIA X Server Settings, the **Intel (Power Saving Mode)** was selected, so I had to choose **NVIDIA (Performance Mode)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
pcsx -v --synce
gdk_x_error -v --sync
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4stLZS1T with comments on top